# Integrating Django with a legacy database does not work

Tags: python, mysql, django

every one: I am trying to practice Integrating Django with a legacy database using django 1.8,mysql db, but it did not success,can any one tell me what's happening??thank you very much!
my  **legacy database**

> models.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone


class blog(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description = models.TextField()
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    date_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name



def get_image_path(instance, filename):
    return '/'.join(['blog_images', instance.bupimg.slug, filename])

class Upload(models.Model):
    bupimg = models.ForeignKey(blog, related_name="uploads")
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_image_path)
```

and I just follow the [doc here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/legacy-databases/)

after I type the command 
[image]

why my pidapp/models.py shows very different than the legacy database's models.py

> pidapp/models.py

```
# This is an auto-generated Django model module.
# You'll have to do the following manually to clean this up:
#   * Rearrange models' order
#   * Make sure each model has one field with primary_key=True
#   * Remove `managed = False` lines if you wish to allow Django to create, modify, and delete the table
# Feel free to rename the models, but don't rename db_table values or field names.
#
# Also note: You'll have to insert the output of 'django-admin sqlcustom [app_label]'

# into your database.

from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import models


class AuthGroup(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=80)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'auth_group'


class AuthGroupPermissions(models.Model):
    group = models.ForeignKey(AuthGroup)
    permission = models.ForeignKey('AuthPermission')

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'auth_group_permissions'
        unique_together = (('group', 'permission'),)


class AuthPermission(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    content_type = models.ForeignKey('DjangoContentType')
    codename = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'auth_permission'
        unique_together = (('content_type', 'codename'),)


class AuthUser(models.Model):
    password = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    is_superuser = models.IntegerField()
    username = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=30)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=254)
    is_staff = models.IntegerField()
    is_active = models.IntegerField()
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField()

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'auth_user'


class AuthUserGroups(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(AuthUser)
    group = models.ForeignKey(AuthGroup)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'auth_user_groups'
        unique_together = (('user', 'group'),)


class AuthUserUserPermissions(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(AuthUser)
    permission = models.ForeignKey(AuthPermission)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'auth_user_user_permissions'
        unique_together = (('user', 'permission'),)


class BloggingBlog(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description = models.TextField()
    slug = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=50)
    date_time = models.DateTimeField()

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'blogging_blog'


class BloggingUpload(models.Model):
    bupimg = models.ForeignKey(BloggingBlog)
    image = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'blogging_upload'


class DjangoAdminLog(models.Model):
    action_time = models.DateTimeField()
    object_id = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    object_repr = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    action_flag = models.SmallIntegerField()
    change_message = models.TextField()
    content_type = models.ForeignKey('DjangoContentType', blank=True, null=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(AuthUser)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'django_admin_log'


class DjangoContentType(models.Model):
    app_label = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    model = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'django_content_type'
        unique_together = (('app_label', 'model'),)


class DjangoMigrations(models.Model):
    app = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    applied = models.DateTimeField()

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'django_migrations'


class DjangoSession(models.Model):
    session_key = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=40)
    session_data = models.TextField()
    expire_date = models.DateTimeField()

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'django_session'


class RegistrationRegistrationprofile(models.Model):
    activation_key = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    user = models.ForeignKey(AuthUser, unique=True)
    activated = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'registration_registrationprofile'
```

I thought the pidapp/models.py should be same as the legacy database's models.py

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you're doing makes no sense. You already have a models.py, why are you trying to create a new one? A "legacy db" in this context refers to a database that has been created outside of Django, and so has no models.py. There's absolutely no reason to run inspectdb on a db that already has models defined.

(Plus, the generated models are correct, anyway; the file contains models for all the existing tables in your database, including the blogging ones, but also including all the other Django tables. Again, there is *no point* in running inspectdb here.)

Comment: right,,,actually I am just practice if I can Integrating Django with a legacy database or not ,,so I created an models.py and try to inspectdb  it from another django project ,,,however I need to know how can I do it

Comment: But you *did* it, and your models have correctly been generated. What exactly is the problem with the output you show?

Comment: I thought the models.py should be same code,,,but it did not,,,you mean in my mysql ,,their table already Integrating??

Comment: You're still not explaining what you think is different. It's obviously not going to be identical code, because it's generated automatically. But it is basically the same, isn't it? If you don't think so, you should point to something specific you think is wrong.

Comment: sorry ,,,I made mistook,,,the table should be the same,,,because it is same db,,,.yes the pidapp/models.py class BloggingBlog is same as legacy db  class blog,,but there is no def get_image_path in pidapp/models.py,,,so I have to add it by my own or,,,does it has automatic way??

Comment: Of course you'll need to add it yourself. How could Django generate it from the database?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106896/discussion-between-cc-l-and-daniel-roseman).